# adding html to ng-include(d) div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I have the following angular template:

```
<script type='text/ng-template' id='template1.html'>
  <h1>hello!</h1>
</script>

<div ng-include src="'template1.html'"></div>
```

Which works perfectly.

Now, I would like to change the last like to something like:

```
<div ng-include src="'template1.html'">
  <h2>Result: {{ 2+2 }}</h2>
</div>
```

So that the div would contain "Hello! 4". But it appears that the whole content of the div is replaced by the template. Is there any way to achieve what I want to do with angularjs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ng-include directive replaces the main element where is placed, if you want to "include" another template into an existent element, you should have to change your code to:

```
<div>
  Hello: <ng-include src="'template1.html'"></ng-include>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, `ngInclude` replaces the whole element.
To obtain what you want, I see 2 ways:

1. template1.html can have optionally a 'result' value:

```
<script type='text/ng-template' id='template1.html'>
  <h2 ng-if="result">Result: {{ result }}</h2>
  <h1>hello!</h1>
</script>

<div ng-include ng-init="result=2+2" src="'template1.html'">
  <h2>Result: {{ 2+2 }}</h2>
</div>
```

1. create a custom [directive](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/guide/directive) where you do what you want; something roughly like:

   angular.module('ngHtmlInjection', [])
     .directive('ngHtmlInjection', function(){
       return {
         restrict: 'A',
         transclude: true,
         scope: {
           myResult     : '@ngResult'
         },
         controller: function($scope){
           $scope.myResult = $scope.result;

   ```
     },
     template:
       '<div>' +
         '<h2 ng-if="myResult">{{ result }}</h2>' +
         '<h1>hello!</h1>' +
       '</div>',
     replace: true
   };
   ```

   });

and your html will be like:

```
<div ng-html-injection ng-result="{{ 2+2 }}">
</div>
```